# python flask markupsafe error(python 3.6.3 version)

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

I'm trying to install flask in python virtualenv. During installation I keep getting an error which is below.

I tried reinstalling many times but did not find any proper solution.

```
(venv) C:\Windows\System32\venv\Scripts>pip install flask
Collecting flask
  Using cached Flask-0.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Jinja2>=2.4 (from flask)
  Using cached Jinja2-2.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.7 in c:\windows\system32\venv\lib\site-packages (from flask)
Collecting click>=2.0 (from flask)
  Using cached click-6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.21 in c:\windows\system32\venv\lib\site-packages (from flask)
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2>=2.4->flask)
  Using cached MarkupSafe-1.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: MarkupSafe
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for MarkupSafe ... error
  Failed building wheel for MarkupSafe
  Running setup.py clean for MarkupSafe
Failed to build MarkupSafe
Installing collected packages: MarkupSafe, Jinja2, click, flask
  Running setup.py install for MarkupSafe ... error
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\windows\system32\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 52: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\windows\system32\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\windows\system32\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\windows\system32\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\windows\system32\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "c:\windows\system32\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "c:\windows\system32\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
    return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 52: invalid start byte
```

Comment: try to update your pip to latest version